Relationship between power per square meter of UV radiation and UV index
I have a couple of UV radiation sensors, the one allows me to obtain the power per square meter and additionally the radiation index.

On the other hand, the other sensor only delivers power per square meter.
When I asked the sensor manufacturer if there was a way to also obtain the UV index, he told me that this model didn't do it, however, the UV level is obtained by dividing by 10, the value of the measured radiation. [W/m2]
Is that correct?
Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Just a thought, but wouldn't the UV index (which I presume is for its effect on human skin) be wavelength dependent?

@Transistor It is. But the index is approximate anyway, as the spectrum varies and different skin types react differently based on individual so it does not matter. It's just an index based on Diffey weighted UV irrandiance of  midday summer sunlight which was around 250mW/m^2 and that was divided by 25 to come up with index 10 for that.

@Transistor Perhaps the sensor either straight up matches the slope needed or have a filter for it? Similar to human eye response for a light meter or A weighted curve for a sound meter?

Not correct.
Each UV index step is 25 mW/m^2 so dividing by 10 can't work.

25mW/m^2 or  250mW/m^2

@FabiánRomo I wrote 25 per one UV index step.

Ok, thanks, what happened is that I was looking for more info and I found that value (250), even in the OP's comments, someone tells me the same thing 250 mW/m^2
